# Centos 7 custom bash script service does not work

Tags: bash, centos, systemd

I had created a deamon in centos 7 to send an email from email queue.

Email queue is implemented in Yii1. That works fine but when I tried to create and run daemon in server but it fails and shows an error :

```
echo "Error! Could not start MyStaging!"
```

I am following instructions which I found [here](http://wiki.contribs.org/Add_a_custom_service).

On inspection I found that `PID` gets the value 1232 and `pgrep -u $RUNAS -f $NAME > /dev/null` command returns empty.

Below is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: MyStaging
# Required-Start: $local_fs $network $named $time $syslog
# Required-Stop: $local_fs $network $named $time $syslog
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Description: This service having purpose to send email from email queue where relevant email push by particular module operation in queue.
### END INIT INFO

SCRIPT="/usr/bin/php5 /home/my/public_html/staging/protected/yiic mailqueue run"
RUNAS=root
NAME=MyStagingMailQueue

PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
LOGFILE=/var/log/$NAME.log

start() {
 if [ -f $PIDFILE ] && kill -0 $(cat $PIDFILE); then
echo 'Service already running' >&2
   return 1
 fi
echo 'Starting service   ' >&2
 local CMD="$SCRIPT &> \"$LOGFILE\" & echo \$!"
# su -s /bin/sh $RUNAS -c "$CMD" > "$PIDFILE"
# Try with this command line instead of above if not workable
 su -c "$CMD" $RUNAS > "$PIDFILE"
sleep 2
 PID=$(cat $PIDFILE)
   if pgrep -u $RUNAS -f $NAME > /dev/null
   then
     echo "$NAME is now running, the PID is $PID"
   else
     echo "Error! Could not start $NAME!"
   fi
}

stop() {
 if [ ! -f "$PIDFILE" ] || ! kill -0 $(cat "$PIDFILE"); then
echo 'Service not running' >&2
   return 1
 fi
echo 'Stopping service   ' >&2
 kill -15 $(cat "$PIDFILE") && rm -f "$PIDFILE"
 echo 'Service stopped' >&2
}

status() {
       printf "%-50s" "Checking $NAME..."
   if [ -f $PIDFILE ]; then
       PID=$(cat $PIDFILE)
           if [ -z "$(ps axf | grep ${PID} | grep -v grep)" ]; then
               printf "%s\n" "The process appears to be dead but pidfile still exists"
           else
               echo "Running, the PID is $PID"
           fi
   else
       printf "%s\n" "Service not running"
   fi
}

case "$1" in
 start)
   start
   ;;
 stop)
   stop
   ;;
 status)
   status
   ;;
 restart)
   stop
   start
   ;;
 *)
   echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}"
esac
```

I don't know what is the issue. Please help me sort it out.

Comment: Please put `pgrep -u $RUNAS -f $NAME > /dev/null` just below the line `PID=$(cat $PIDFILE)` and do an `echo $?` after that. We should get `0` if the `pgrep` command ran fine.

Comment: Also, I would double check the process name is exactly `MyStagingMailQueue`.

Comment: Thank you @Sjsam,
Option1: PID=$(cat $PIDFILE)       
  if "pgrep -u $RUNAS -f $NAME > /dev/null & echo $?"; then
Option2: PID=$(cat $PIDFILE)
  if pgrep -u $RUNAS -f $NAME > /dev/null & echo $?
  then
but both way shows process is running but when I show status then it shows "The process appears to be dead but pidfile still exists" I don't know how to get out this issue.

Comment: sJam when I execute command "service mystagingmailqueue start" it returns service is starting but when I execute " service mystagingmailqueue status" it returns "The process appears to be dead but pidfile still exists". I hope you may get answer of your question.

Comment: I understand that pal, But please check why it crashes immediately after starting.

Comment: Can i show you my php script?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98975/discussion-between-dipak-chavda-and-sjsam).

Comment: CentOS 7 uses `systemd`. This script is a `sysvinit` script. Creating a native systemd unit/service file it likely a better place to start for a CentOS 7 service.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using CentOS 7, it's better to create a `systemd service`.

**Step1:**

Create a service file for your service say `yiicmail.service`. Do :

```
sudo touch /etc/systemd/system/yiicmail.service
```

**Step2:**

Open the the above file with your favourite editor and put the below content in it:

```
[Unit]
Description=yiic service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
ExecStart="/usr/bin/php5 /home/whizbite/public_html/staging/protected/yiic mailqueue run"
#If there are spaces, I would strings within quotes like above
Restart=on-abort


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Step3:**

Now it is the time to play with the service. To start it, do :

```
sudo systemctl start yiicmail # You don't have to type full name, that is, yiicmail.service
```

To check the status, do :

```
sudo systemctl status yiicmail
```

To stop it, do :

```
sudo systemctl stop yiicmail
```

To start the service at boot, do :

```
sudo systemctl enable yiicmail
```

To disable the service at boot, do:

```
sudo systemctl disable yiicmail
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sjsam, So you mean to say I used below command rather than "pgrep -u $RUNAS -f $NAME > /dev/null". And I don't know why script terminates. I am setting up my script on centos 7 server.

Comment: Output ::
Starting service   
0
MyStagingEmailQueue is now running, the PID is 781
root@wb01-development [~]# ps -p $(sudo cat /var/run/MyStagingMailQueue.pid) -o comm= : nothing returns

Comment: Sorry, not able to understand what you have said.. What is the output you got when you run the command `ps -p $(sudo cat /var/run/MyStagingMailQueue.pid) -o comm=`

Comment: But you said the process is running. Could you check and confirm the name of the pid file inside `/var/log`?

Comment: No.. when I execute command "service mystagingemailqueue start/restart" returns "process is now running. you pid is <123>"  but when immediately execute "service mystagingemailqueue status" returns "The process appears to be dead but pidfile still exists"

Comment: Then troubleshoot the problem with the service first before you proceed with this question. Check why the service `mystagingemailqueue` stops immediately. Again we have to check the `.log` file for the service. :) Good luck with this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98980/discussion-between-sjsam-and-dipak-chavda).